# Datatables: when shoudl I use mdata/mrender or data/render?

Tags: datatables

I am quite confused with datatable API
Sometimes it uses mdata, mrender, sometimes it uses data, render

I am using that snipper:

```
{ mData: 'deadline', "title":"Deadline", "render": function(data, type, row) {
                var recurrence = row.rec_description;                    
                return sprintf("<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> %s <div>(%s)</div>\
                <div><i class='fa fa-recycle'></i> Récurrence:%s</div>\
                ",
                    moment(data,'X').format('DD/MM/YYYY'),  moment(data,'X').locale('fr').fromNow(), recurrence);
            } },
```

Which works fine, however sorting on that column does not work: 
Maybe this is because of the use of "mData, render" ?

deadline is an int(15) but it looks it sorts by html content.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery DataTables 1.9 used Hungarian notation (`mData`, `mRender`) in option names, jQuery Datatables 1.10 switched to camel case notation (`data`, `render`) but still supports option names from 1.9.

If you're using jQuery DataTables 1.10, I would recommend to switch to camel case notation, since support for Hungarian notation option names could be dropped in the next major version.

In order to be able to sort by `deadline`, you need to rewrite your `render` function as shown below. It produces HTML content only when data is displayed, otherwise for sorting it returns raw data.

```
{ 
   "data": "deadline", 
   "title":"Deadline", 
   "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
      if(type === "display"){
            var recurrence = row.rec_description;                    
            data = sprintf(
               "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> %s <div>(%s)</div>"
                  + "<div><i class='fa fa-recycle'></i> Récurrence:%s</div>",
               moment(data,'X').format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
               moment(data,'X').locale('fr').fromNow(), 
               recurrence
            );
      } 

      return data;
   }
},
```

See [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for more information.

Comment: One thing to watch out for in this situation is scoping / closure issues where some value outside the scope of the render definition is needed or referenced. In that case, make a function in your "class" scope called makeRenderer or some such that accepts the outside params you need. Have makeRenderer return the actual html rendering function. Assign this function to "render".

Comment: I think that *recurrence* should be escaped to avoid XSS issues.